# Image couldn't load in picture control in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am new to MFC and I have to load the image by a button in the picture control. I had done this much code in the button handler but the BMP picture can't load up in the picture control.

```
    CImage img;
    HRESULT hr = img.Load(sPath);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString sErrorMsg;
        sErrorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to load %s"), sPath);
        AfxMessageBox(sErrorMsg);
        return;
    }

    CRect rect;
    m_picturecontrol.GetClientRect(rect);
    int nWidth = rect.Width();
    int nHeight = rect.Height();

    CDC* pScreenDC = GetDC();
    CDC MemDC;
    MemDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pScreenDC);
    CBitmap bmp;
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pScreenDC, nWidth, nHeight);

    CBitmap* pOldObj = MemDC.SelectObject(&bmp);
    img.StretchBlt(MemDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 0, 0, img.GetWidth(), img.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
    MemDC.SelectObject(pOldObj);

    m_picturecontrol.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)bmp.Detach());
    ReleaseDC(pScreenDC);
}
```

}

Comment: What's the specific problem you are trying to solve, and how does it fail? Please see [ask].

Comment: I tried to load the picture in the picture control dynamically. first I create a picture control and add a variable. then I created a button to load pictures in the picture control rectangle. I added a button handler and wrote the above code. but after inserting the file , the image didn't insert.

Comment: It's wrong, you don't actually need to draw the image (`GetDC()/StretchBlt()/ReleaseDC()`) to load a bitmap into a static/`SS_BITMAP` control. Where did you find this? `SetBitmap()` should be enough. You must also delete the previously loaded bitmap if any, otherwise this causes leakages.

Comment: @con The `StretchBlt` call is intended to create a bitmap that matches the client area of the static control. If you don't to that, the control would resize to match the image. The previously loaded image is properly cleaned up. `img` is a variable with automatic storage duration, and when it goes out of scope it cleans up the resources it owns.

Comment: @IInspectable my bad. So the code creates a new (stretched) bitmap and loads that one in the control. Then some debugging/tracing can show which operation fails.

Comment: The previously loaded bitmap (ia any) must be deleted though. `CStatic.SetBitmap()` has an inline implementation which just sends the `STM_SETIMAGE` message. Not that this is the reason why this code doesn't work, of course.

Comment: That's correct. As always, the MFC documentation is a lot less complete than the Windows API documentation. [`STM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/stm-setimage) has remarks on the resource management requirements.

Comment: @sumit Could you provide a minimal  example that can be executed and reproduce the problem? It will help everyone to reproduce your problem.